# Why static implicit operator doesn't work on DynamicObject inherited classes ? And how to fix it?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Code :

```
public class t : System.Dynamic.DynamicObject
{

    public dynamic Value;

    public static implicit operator t(int value)
    {
        if (value > 100) value = 100;
        t x = new t();
        x.Value = value;
        return x;
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
dynamic f = new t();
f = 44; // the implicit operator doesn't get called
```

However if I change `implicit` to `explicit` and use it like `f = (int)44)` the explicit operator is called.

EDIT: I want my class to inherit from DynamicObject.

How to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use:

```
dynamic f = new t();  // f has type 'dynamic', no compile-time link between f and type 't'
f = 44; // the implicit operator doesn't get called
```

Why would assigning `44` to a variable of type `dynamic` convert that `44` through any user-defined operator? It simply puts `44` (or rather a boxed `44`) into `f`.

Compare with:

```
t f = new t();
f = 44;
```

Comment: Yes you code works fine but it doesn't allow me to do `f.member = value`

Comment: @Mahdi So what is `.member` here? Do you need an expando object (one that acquires magically any property you happen to use with it)? Because .NET has that.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `f = 44;`, it is not changing the *value* of the object.  Rather, it is reassigning the `f` variable to point to a *new object*.  By default, the new object will be an `int`, since it's an `int` literal.  If you want to create a `new t` object that equals `44`, you need to cast it to that type, like this:

```
f = (t)44;
```